# How to simulate Power Failure In Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine

I have my `rook-ceph`cluster running on `AWS`. Its loaded up with data.
Is there's any way to stimulate **POWER FAILURE**  so that I can test the behaviour of my cluster?.

Comment: rook is not ok for production. It is very unstable and you can not resize your volume.

Comment: for power failure you can reboot your host.
but I think you mean another thing

Comment: What do you mean by host?.

Comment: I know rook is unstable. By I I'm running rook-ceph. Do you know how to simulate Power Failure?.

Comment: you should have kubernetes to run rook. there should be a host that kubernetes and therir worker install on it. you should reboot them.

Comment: I'm using Kubernetes only to run my `rook-ceph` cluster. What is host actually? I'm not getting what are you trying to say by that?.

Answer (score 3):

From Docker you can send KILL signal "SIGPWR" that [Power failure (System V)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

```
docker kill --signal="SIGPWR"
```

and from Kubernet

```
kubectl exec <pod> -- /killme.sh
```

and so scriplt killme.sh

```
beginning of script-----
#!/bin/bash
# Define process to find
kiperf=$(pidof iperf)
# Kills all iperf or command line
kill -30 $kiperf
script end -------------
```

signal 30 you can find [here](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/1676-simple-way-to-kill-a-pid-processid-from-cli-or-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 3):

It depends what is the purpose of your crash test. I see two options:

1. You want to test if you correctly deployed Kubernetes on AWS - then, I'd terminate the related AWS EC2 Instance (or set of Instances)
2. You want to test if your end application is resilient to Kubernetes Node failures - then I'd just check what PODs are running on the given Node and kill them all suddenly with:

```
kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Cluster Pods do not disappear till someone (a person or a controller) destroys them, or there is an unavoidable hardware or system software error.

Developers call these unavoidable cases involuntary disruptions to an application. Examples are:

- a hardware failure of the physical machine backing the node
- cluster administrator deletes VM (instance) by mistake
- cloud provider or hypervisor failure makes VM disappear
  a kernel panic
- the node disappears from the cluster due to cluster network partition
- eviction of a pod due to the node being out-of-resources.
  Except for the out-of-resources condition, all these conditions should be familiar to most users; they are not specific to Kubernetes.

Developers call other cases voluntary disruptions. These include both actions initiated by the application owner and those initiated by a Cluster Administrator.

Typical application owner actions include:

- deleting the deployment or other controller that manages the pod
- updating a deployment’s pod template causing a restart
- directly deleting a pod (e.g. by accident)

More information you can find here: [kubernetes-discruption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/),
[application-discruption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/).

You can setup Prometheus on your cluster and mesure metrics during failure.